# Error putting S3 notification configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-sqs

When I try to create a aws_s3_bucket_notification I get this terrerform exception: `aws_s3_bucket_notification.input_notification: Error putting S3 notification configuration: InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations
    status code: 400, request id: 4E17F794B9BC67C9, host id: QmeEFS+T1cvr1xFEMmAlqBKxzX1Fg+qOpwJFXDl4sR1hVcHa4swLN87BiPI8BToGuNQ3oYD0pYk=` As for as I can tell I have followed the specs outlined in the terraform docs here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_notification.html
Has anyone else had this problem before?

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "sqs_queue" {
  name = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
  delay_seconds = 5
  max_message_size = 262144
  message_retention_seconds = 86400
  receive_wait_time_seconds = 10
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 90
  redrive_policy = "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"${aws_sqs_queue.sqs_dlq.arn}\",\"maxReceiveCount\":${var.sqs_max_receive_count}}"

  policy = <<POLICY
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:s3-event-notification-queue",
        "Condition": {
          "ArnEquals": { "aws:SourceArn": "${aws_s3_bucket.input.arn}" }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  POLICY
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "input" {
  bucket = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}-input"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "input_notification" {
    depends_on = [
        "aws_s3_bucket.input",
        "aws_sqs_queue.sqs_queue"
  ]

  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.input.id}"

  queue {
    queue_arn     = "${aws_sqs_queue.sqs_queue.arn}"
    events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_suffix = ".gz"
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a depends_on for queue and the bucket, there used to be a bug where ordering was respected,

Comment: Still get the same error.

Comment: are you sure the resource arn is correct in the policy:  {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:s3-event-notification-queue",
        "Condition": {
          "ArnEquals": { "aws:SourceArn": "${aws_s3_bucket.input.arn}" }
        }
      } - why not use ""${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}""

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The SQS policy was wrong, it should look like this:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "sqs_queue" {
  name = "${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}"
  delay_seconds = 5
  max_message_size = 262144
  message_retention_seconds = 86400
  receive_wait_time_seconds = 10
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 90
  redrive_policy = "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"${aws_sqs_queue.sqs_dlq.arn}\",\"maxReceiveCount\":${var.sqs_max_receive_count}}"

  policy = <<POLICY
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:${var.env}-${var.subenv}-${var.appname}",
        "Condition": {
          "ArnEquals": { "aws:SourceArn": "${aws_s3_bucket.input.arn}" }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  POLICY
}
```

Comment: there should not be a wildcard for principal. the value for `Principal` should be: `{"Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"}`